# EF4 database first configurable schema

Tags: entity-framework-4, database-schema, ef-database-first

I have one issue I am trying to resolve for days now, but I can’t get the right approach.
I am using EF4 and I have one application where I use DataBase First, which originally created the ObjectContext, and I donwloaded the DbContext generator and generated it.

The thing is, I need the application to be able to get the database SCHEMA from some configuration file, instead of ALWAYS using the “dbo” default.
I was trying to use the “ToTable” method (so I can specify the schema) in the “OnModelCreating” overload method but as [this article](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake) sais, as I am using DataBase First, that method is not called.

How can I make the schema name configurable?
Is that even possible?
I read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/07/when-is-code-first-not-code-first.aspx) article too, where it says I can combine database first with code first but I can’t see how to do that if I can’t use the "OnModelCreating" method.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Entity Framework seem to force add `dbo` as the schema, and all the solutions I see always talk about code-first. But you can not solve a database-first issue with a code-first solution, so looking at anything like that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about configuring schema. However if you want your db first approach to changed to the code first, just change the string parameter of your DbContext constructor.

Suppose that you have the following DbContext that EF Db first created for you:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("Name=DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    // DbSets ...
}
```

change that to the following to start using code first and all magic tools of it (migration, etc.):

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("YourDbFileName")
    {

    }

    // DbSets ...
}
```

It causes that EF creates a new connection string using SQL Express on your local machine in your web.config file with the name `YourDbFileName`, something just like the early `DefaultConnection` Db first created.

All you may need to continue your way, is that edit the `YourDbFileName` ConStr according to your server and other options.

Comment: Using any sort of "code-first" when it is a database-first setup makes no sense, so I don't understand what you are trying to answer here.